# A more elgant way to roll up multiple rows?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter (although I suppose this isn't an exclusively CI question) and have a method in a model which selects data from two tables joined by id.

table 1 (tblclients) looks like this:

```
+----+------------+
+ id + c_name     +
+----+------------+
+ 1  + Joe Bloggs +
+ 2  + Jim Bloggs +
+ 3  + Tim Bloggs +
+----+------------+
```

table 2 (tblstars) looks like this:

```
+----+------------+
+ id + s_date     +
+----+------------+
+ 1  + 27/01/12   +
+ 1  + 15/02/12   +
+ 1  + 18/02/12   +
+ 2  + 03/01/12   +
+ 2  + 11/02/12   +
+ 2  + 15/02/12   +
+ 3  + 01/01/12   +
+ 3  + 19/02/12   +
+----+------------+
```

I want to 'roll up' the joined data into one line for each row in tblclients so I can output, for example:

```
+----+------------+--------------------------------+
+ id + Name       +   Dates                        +
+----+------------+--------------------------------+
+ 1  + Joe Bloggs + 27/01/12   15/02/12   18/02/12 +
+ 2  + Jim Bloggs + 03/01/12   11/02/12   15/02/12 +
+ 3  + Tim Bloggs + 01/01/12   19/02/12            +
+----+------------+--------------------------------+
```

Now I've 'solved' the problem by using the following in my model:

```
    function get_clients_concat()
{   
    $query = $this->db
    ->select('tblclients.id, tblclients.c_name, GROUP_CONCAT(tblstars.s_date SEPARATOR "#") AS star_dates', NULL, FALSE)
    ->join('tblstars', 'tblstars.id = tblclients.id', 'left')
    ->order_by('tblclients.id')
    ->group_by('tblclients.id')
    ->get('tblclients');
    return $query->result();        

}
```

and then exploding the array (created by the GROUP_CONCAT) in my view and doing some processing with it there ... but it seems really CLUNKY.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. The alternative would be not to use `GROUP_CONCAT` and use PHP to check when the `id` changes in the iteration.

Comment: thanks for the response. I though maybe I'd m,issed a trick somewhere with the 'rolling up' portion but it seems not. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome. I guess it also depends on the size of you data set. There is probably a performance penalty for using `GROUP_CONCAT`. I am not a MySQL expert. You may get feedback about that if you add the MySQL tag to your question. And you may get further feedback if you also add the PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all that data in a single query (with each row's id unique), then yes--that's the way to go.

If you need to sort or filter the results, you'll run into performance bottlenecks when the tables fill up.

It seems odd though--why wouldn't you select from `tblstars` (joining `tblclients`) instead, then use application logic to index the dates by `c_name`/`id`?

```
<?php

// Select data from tables
$data = $this->db
    ->select('tblclients.id, tblclients.c_name, tblstars.s_date')
    ->join('tblclients', 'tblclients.id = tblstars.id')
    ->order_by('tblstars.id')
    ->get('tblstars');

// Index data by client id
// (keeping record of client name and dates array for each)
$clients = array();
foreach ($data->result() as $result)
{
    if (empty($clients[$result->id]))
    {
        $clients[$result->id] = array(
            'name'  => $result->c_name,
            'dates' => array($result->s_date)
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $clients[$result->id]['dates'][] = $result->s_date;
    }
}

return $clients;
```